# sql - retrieving order

Tags: sql, rdbms

I was explaining my SQL query to a colleague yesterday and he asked me a question I never considered.

Let's say I have a table called `the_table` like this

```
col1            col2
www.toto.com    stuff_wedding
www.toto.com    stuff_boxing
www.toto.com    stuff_love
www.toto.com    stuff_wedding
```

My query is :

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE col1 LIKE '%toto.com%' AND col LIKE '%wedding%';
```

I should get

```
col1            col2
www.toto.com    stuff_wedding
www.toto.com    stuff_wedding
```

The question is the following:

When doing the AND like in my condition, does the SQL parsing go for every line ,looking for toto on col1 and once the query found them , regroup all the results with toto in col1 and look look for wedding in col2 in that specific subset?

Or does it look at any line , look for toto for col1 and then go for col2 if there was a toto in col1 , and look for wedding?

I was a bit puzzled on that one as I've never really thought about it. Plus , does the DB engine has something to do with how the parsing is done?

Thanks

Comment: I think your question is about `RDBMS` behaviors, and you want to know this about all `RDBMS`es ?

Comment: I can't say I know for sure, but it seems decently inefficient to loop through all the records, build a temporary table of the subset, then loop through all those again to check the second condition. I don't see why it wouldn't just look at each row for each condition, then go with that. Indexes would probably affect that, though.

Comment: Hi @shA.t , does the RDBMS determine the way SQL query or does the SQL query has a way of doing things?

Comment: Hi @MatthewHaugen , I agree with you but I was puzzled by his question that's why I'm asking it. But true , it seems a bit inefficient for the first proposal.

Comment: Check your dbms' execution plan. (I guess most dbms will not create a temporary table in this case, that's far too expensive.)

Comment: For SQL server check this [Understanding-how-SQL-Server-executes-a-query](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630346/Understanding-how-SQL-Server-executes-a-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL server check this [Understanding-how-SQL-Server-executes-a-query](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630346/Understanding-how-SQL-Server-executes-a-query)

I think your answer is here:

> **Seek Operator**
>       The seek operator can locate a row directly based on a key. Seek can only operate on B-Tree organized data sources, so it can only be
>   applied to Clustered and Nonclustered indexes. If an index has a
>   complex key (multiple columns) then the Seek operator can only operate
>   if values for the leftmost keys in the index definition are provided.
>   To give an example, if an index has the key columns (A, B, C) then the
>   Seek can locate the first row where A='a', or the first row where
>   A='a' AND B='b' or the first row where A='a' AND B='b' AND C='c'.
>   However, on such an index, Seek cannot locate a row where B='b' or a
>   row where C='c'. Seek operator is also capable of implementing ranges.
>   Given the same index definition on (A, B, C) a Seek operator can
>   iterate all rows where A > 'a' AND A < 'z' or all rows where A = 'a'
>   AND B > 'b' AND B < 'z', but it cannot iterate rows where B > 'b' AND
>   B < 'z'. If you inspect an execution plan you will possibly see any of
>   the operators Clustered Index Seek, or Remote Index Seek. They are
>   distinct operators because they apply to different data sources, but
>   they all have in common the capability to efficiently locate locate a
>   row base dona key value or to iterate efficiently over a range of key
>   values. Obviously there are no heap seek operators, as heaps, being
>   unordered, do not have the capability to locate a row efficiently
>   based on a key. Seek should be be the preferred data access method in
>   almost every situation.

Comment: you nailed it. I don't have an index but the way the seek operator works , can be applied to my context. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyK, so you say your question is about SQL Server, not just general dbms theory?

Comment: @jarth , about general dbms theory. But can we say that the SQL server example can be extrapolated to all general theory?